# Laptop booting to bios only - no bootable drives

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, bios

I have got myself into a situation with my Asus Zenbook UX310U laptop where it now only boots into the BIOS and does not recognise and drives in the Boot menu.

The laptop comes with two drives, a regular HDD and an SSD.

I was using some freeware, Disk genius, to perform a system migration to the SSD. When going through their wizard to perform this task I had an option to change the boot device to the SSD after migration was performed.

In doing this, the laptop has rebooted and I got do prompt s reen telling me to insert media to boot from and press a key. I didn't get any media created as part of the disk genius steps. I went into BIOS and fiddled around with changing boot orders and have now ended up with laptop booting to BIOS and it no longer seeing any drives in the Boot menu.

I am not worried about losing data from original HDD as I have already backed up personal files externally.

But I am confused as to what's happened here.

If I go to the Advanced bios menu and Sata Configuration, I do see the drives listed.

I am only wanting to get windows installed onto SSD, so happy to do this from scratch again. Would my best option be to create a bootable USB drive and go down that route?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the system migration did not go well. You should do a clean system installation and later copy back your data. If your data is on the drive that you plan to install the system, just content it to a different computer, and copy your files to another drive, and than do a clean system installation.

Answer (score 0):

The very first would be for the BIOS to recognize both hard drives again. When this is done, there might still be a chance to get things fixed.

Was the laptop equipped with both hard drives from the beginning?

My proposal:

- invoke the hard disc diagnostics menu from the BIOS
- scan for disks
- if it does not find any, bring the machine back to its original config (I am guessing that you installed the second hard drive later on by yourself)
- repeat the scan